# The react-select module cannot find react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-select

React-select cannot find React:
TypeError: React is undefined1 react-select.js:826:4

React-select.js is getting react through

```
var React = (window.React);
```

It lookes like i have to include React in the html to make this work, but i would like to avoid this. Is there something i am missing?

(using node)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me guess, you require [dist/react-select.js](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/dist/react-select.js). This script is used for browser environment. Try to require node environment script, which described in [package.json](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/package.json#L5). Or if you use `npm install react-select` it enough to call `require('react-select');`

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why i get `Error: Invariant Violation: React.render(): Invalid component element. This may be caused by unintentionally loading two independent copies of React.1 react.js:18472:14` ? Seems like react-select drag in another copy of React.

Comment: I think it's the same problem with react module. May be you require it for browser environment. Check out [Modules Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) and [NPM Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com). Then install `react` and `react-select` through `npm`.

Answer (score 1):

We need some more clarification here, "using node" - are you rendering on node server?

If you are rendering in the client/browser, `var React = (window.React);` can possibly be called before `window.React` is available...

I recommend using commonJs pattern ie: `var React = require('React');`

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer will solve some of your issues with React. To start off, React is not the most 'noob' frendily 'View'(MVC).

I personally believe that HTML should only handle any Javascript. Let's separate the concerns into two.

---

|-- index.html

|-- app.js

Now, we have two files with two separate concerns. I do agree that the proper way to 'requiring' <== current way  || 'import' new ES6way (AS of Release of Node 6) but for the simplicity sake, let's use CDNs.
Add these script tags

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js'></script>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js'> </script>
```

"Keep clam =*= solve bugs"